# IBM MQ Error - Completion Code 1, Reason 2003

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am getting the below error while the application polls the messages from different queues (using IBM MQ) and load the same into the some staging tables.

`....- Completion Code 1, Reason 2003
 com.ibm.mq.MQException: Completion Code 1, Reason 2003
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.commit(MQQueueManager.java:795)`

Your help in resolving this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the manual (InfoCenter): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc/fm12100_.htm

How often is your code doing a commit?